# Inheritance interface as return type - Cannot convert expression

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have the following

```
public interface IAwesomeInterface
{
    string Prop1 {get; set;}
    string Prop2 {get; set;}

    List<SomeObject> GetObjects();
}

public abstract class AbstractObject : IAwesomeInterface 
{
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}

    public abstract List<SomeObject> GetObjects();

}

public class ConcreteObject1 : AbstractObject
{
    public List<SomeObject> GetObjects()
    {
        return new List<SomeObject>();
    }
}

public class ConcreteObject2 : AbstractObject
{
    public List<SomeObject> GetObject()
    {
        //do some other stuff
        return new List<SomeObject>();
    }
}
```

and an implementation of:

```
public class ObjectFactory
{

    public IAwesomeInterface GetObject()
    {

        return new ConcreteObject1();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error that "Cannot convert expression type ConcreteObject1 to return type IAwesomeInterface"

Since ConcreteObject1 inherits from AbstractObject, doesn't that mean that it implements IAwesomeInterface and should be an acceptable return value?

Comment: FYI, might have been a copy/paste error, but your `ConcreteObject2.GetObject` method is typo'd (should be `GetObjects`, plural)

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo for the question. The problem was that I didn't override the abstract method.

Answer (score 6):

Your code throws also another error, which is the reason the second one exists:

> 'ConcreteObject1' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AbstractObject.GetObjects()'

Fix this one, and the one you've quoted will go away too. To do that, add `override` next to  `GetObjects()` method in both `ConcreteObject1` and `ConcreteObject2`:

```
public class ConcreteObject1 : AbstractObject
{
    public override List<SomeObject> GetObjects()
    {
        return new List<SomeObject>();
    }
}

public class ConcreteObject2 : AbstractObject
{
    public override List<SomeObject> GetObjects()
    {
        //do some other stuff
        return new List<SomeObject>();
    }
}
```

PS. Your code had a typo in `GetObjects` method name. You missed `s` at the end of method name.